# Active Worksheet vs Calling Worksheet

Tags: excel, worksheet

I have an Excel VBA function (below) which is called from several worksheets and references a local named cell whose value is different in each worksheet. When I update my workbook by hitting <kbd>F9</kbd>, each call to the function produces an identical result, because all calls to the function pick up the local cell value from the worksheet which is the focus when I hit the <kbd>F9</kbd> key. I now understand that this is how the "active" worksheet is defined. I want to pick up the value of the local named cell in each worksheet from which the function is called. Can someone tell me how to do this?

```
Function AcquisDate()
    Application.Volatile True
    [WOULD LIKE TO SET ACTIVE WORKSHEET TO CALLING WORKSHEET HERE
    AcquisDate = Range("AcquisDateCell") 'This cell name is local to each worksheet.
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Application.Caller.Parent.Range(...) like in example below

```
Function AcquisDate()
    Application.Volatile True
    AcquisDate = Application.Caller.Parent.Range("AcquisDateCell")
End Function
```

Comment: @user1787425, when you come back this way be sure to accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.